# Send Kafka stream join output to a topic with schema

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to push KStream - KStream join to a output kafka topic. On this output topic I have a elasticsearch sink connector listening. Currently when i push joins output to topic, it only sends the model in json format. I want to send the schema of model also so that elasticsearch sink connector can get the schema and dump data to elasticsearch.

Following is my code snippet:

```
  KStream<String, String> rightSource = builder.stream("my-kafka-right-stream-topic");
 
  KStream<String, String> joined = leftSource.join(rightSource,
      (leftValue, rightValue) -> "left=" + leftValue + ", right=" + rightValue, /* ValueJoiner */
      JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(5)),
      Joined.with(
          Serdes.String(), /* key */
          Serdes.String(),   /* left value */
          Serdes.String())  /* right value */
  );
 
  joined.to("my-kafka-stream-stream-inner-join-out");
```

Is this even possible ? or is there any other way to dump output to elasticsearh using sink connector ?

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "schema of model". You're sending strings, so if the schema is part of the JSON message, it will be sent. You're never introducing any JSON libraries here to do anything different

Comment: You can also save the data of `my-kafka-stream-stream-inner-join-out without schema` using the `"schema.ignore": "true"` etc. Can you use that approach in this case?